# What can I do to get informed for every new inspector

Tags: outlook, vsto, ribbon

I need to subsribe to events for every new inspector that will be opend.
And also want to invalidate the ribbon on every new Inspector.

Ther is an event that will be called for every new inspector:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Inspectors.NewInspector += (sender, explorer) => ribbon.Invalidate();
```

However this event will not be called when a new inspector is opend via the `send to -> Mail recipient` from the windowsd explorer.

Another aproach was to register to the UI events in the ribbon. But those will also not called every time a new window is opend.

Is there is any way to reliable get notified for every new inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NewInspector does not fire on purpose when a new message is created using Simple MAPI or fro ma mailto link.

You can have a timer that wakes up every couple seconds and checks if the `Application.Inspectors` collection has any new inspectors you have not processed yet.

Comment: Wenn you say on purpose, what is the purpose that it is not fired. And that there is no alternative for it in those cases? It seems to be a valid usecase to get informed when ever a user creates a new mail (I haven't seen a OnNewMailItem event)

Comment: They were running into problems with inspectors created by Simple MAPI call or mailto links. The only viable fix was to disable the event in that scenario. That is what I heard.